# How to archive a message using ruby `net/imap`

Tags: ruby, imap

With the following ruby code, I can read a user's mail in an inbox via IMAP:

```
require 'net/imap'
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com',993,true)
imap.login('user','passwd')
imap.select('INBOX')
mailIds = imap.search(['ALL'])
mailIds.each do |id|
  msg = imap.fetch(id,'RFC822')[0].attr['RFC822']
  puts msg
end 
imap.logout()
imap.disconnect()
```

I want to know how I can archive and mark read emails. I want to move the emails out of the user's inbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`store` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html#method-i-store)

```
require 'net/imap'
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, true)
imap.login('user', 'passwd')
imap.select('INBOX')
mailIds = imap.search(['ALL'])
mailIds.each do |id|
  msg = imap.fetch(id, 'RFC822')[0].attr['RFC822']
  puts msg
  imap.store(id, "+FLAGS", [:Seen])
end 
imap.logout()
imap.disconnect()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on GMail boxes: STORE attempt on READ-ONLY folder (Failure)

Comment: Have you explicitly selected a folder? It didn't work for me until I added the folder selection there (imap.select 'INBOX')